# How can change font size in UWP TimePikcerFlyout?

Tags: c#, uwp, styles, font-size, flyout

I want to make the font size of TimePickerFlyout bigger, It's Possible?

[image: UWP TimePickerFlyout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area that you pointed is `LoopingSelector` of [`TimerPicker`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.timepicker). And the default font size is 15 in [`LoopingSelector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.loopingselector) style like the following.

```
<Style TargetType="LoopingSelector">
    <Setter Property="ShouldLoop" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}" />
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PrimaryText}" FontFamily="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" FontSize="15" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Control">
                <Grid>

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />

                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="UpButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DownButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>

                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer"
                VerticalSnapPointsType="Mandatory"
                VerticalSnapPointsAlignment="Near"
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled"
                ZoomMode="Disabled"
                Template="{StaticResource ScrollViewerScrollBarlessTemplate}" />
                    <RepeatButton x:Name="UpButton"
                Content="&#xE70E;"
                FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
                FontSize="8"
                Height="22"
                Padding="0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Visibility="Collapsed"
                Style="{StaticResource DateTimePickerFlyoutButtonStyle}"
                Background="{ThemeResource LoopingSelectorButtonBackground}"
                IsTabStop="False" />
                    <RepeatButton x:Name="DownButton"
                Content="&#xE70D;"
                FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
                FontSize="8"
                Height="22"
                Padding="0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                Visibility="Collapsed"
                Style="{StaticResource DateTimePickerFlyoutButtonStyle}"
                Background="{ThemeResource LoopingSelectorButtonBackground}"
                IsTabStop="False" />

                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

If you want to make it more bigger. you just modify the following font size to another value. Then place complete style in `<Application.Resources>` in the App.xaml file.

`<TextBlock Text="{Binding PrimaryText}" FontFamily="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" FontSize="15" />`

Comment: So thanks,
This is correct! I can don't use it in Application resources and have it in page resource for example?

Comment: I tried use it in page resource, but it does not work, because It renderer in flyout control.